# How to find the nvidia GPU IDs for pytorch cuda run setup?

Tags: python, linux, gpu, deviceid

One major issue most young data scientists, enthusiasts ask me is how to find the GPU IDs to map in the `Pytorch` code?

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

This can be easily found with this piece of code down below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import torch
import sys
print('__Python VERSION:', sys.version)
print('__pyTorch VERSION:', torch.__version__)
print('__CUDA VERSION')
from subprocess import call
# call(["nvcc", "--version"]) does not work
! nvcc --version
print('__CUDNN VERSION:', torch.backends.cudnn.version())
print('__Number CUDA Devices:', torch.cuda.device_count())
print('__Devices')
call(["nvidia-smi", "--format=csv", "--query-gpu=index,name,driver_version,memory.total,memory.used,memory.free"])
print('Active CUDA Device: GPU', torch.cuda.current_device())
print ('Available devices ', torch.cuda.device_count())
print ('Current cuda device ', torch.cuda.current_device())
```

This will produce the below output:

```
__Python VERSION: 3.8.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 25 2022, 06:04:10) 
[GCC 10.3.0]
__pyTorch VERSION: 1.12.0a0+bd13bc6
__CUDA VERSION
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Mar__8_18:18:20_PST_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.124
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.31057947_0
__CUDNN VERSION: 8400
__Number CUDA Devices: 2
__Devices
index, name, driver_version, memory.total [MiB], memory.used [MiB], memory.free [MiB]

0, Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, 470.103.01, 32510 MiB, 3381 MiB, 29129 MiB
1, Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB, 470.103.01, 32510 MiB, 684 MiB, 31826 MiB

Active CUDA Device: GPU 0
Available devices  2
Current cuda device  0
```

or

```
import pycuda
from pycuda import compiler
import pycuda.driver as drv

drv.init()
print("%d device(s) found." % drv.Device.count())
           
for ordinal in range(drv.Device.count()):
    dev = drv.Device(ordinal)
    print (ordinal, dev.name())
```

This will produce the below output

```
2 device(s) found.
0 Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB
1 Tesla V100-SXM2-32GB
```

If you get an error of `pycuda` module not found, you can simply do a `pip` install.

```
pip install pycuda
```